# RegEx Pattern not matching in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I want to know why this regex group is not working for me in JAVA? It's throwing exception while finding match of group. I am trying to match the numbers separated by dashes.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("1-1-3-1-4");
matcher.group(0); // Exception happens here - java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

Comment: No.  Could you please point, if anything specific to take a look which is causing this issue?

Comment: Using `matcher()` doesn't actually try to match anything.  It just sets the matcher up.  You have to tell it to try a match with one of the [`Matcher` methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: use `matcher.find()` to iterate over all occurances.

Comment: that's what he is doing by using `group`

Comment: @f.khantsis [Have a look at this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Matcher#find()` to actually get a match:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher("1-1-3-1-4");
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0))
}
```

If you were expecting multiple matches, you could use a `while` loop instead of an `if` statement.

Also note that you actually have *five* capture groups in your patterns.  Capture groups are denoted by placing a portion of the pattern in parentheses.  If you don't intend/need to capture the five separated numbers in your pattern individually, then you can consider telling the regex engine *not* to capture them, e.g. use this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[0-9]+)-(?:[0-9]+)-(?:[0-9]+)-(?:[0-9]+)-(?:[0-9]+)");
```

## Demo

Comment: It should match this pattern but, right ?

Comment: Group zero matches the entire pattern.  On top of this, you have five capture groups in there.  If you can tell us more about what you are trying to do here, I can update my answer.

Comment: Okey, I got it, after using matcher.find() it worked for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java regex **`index`** or **`study`** methods are used to return  `Matcher` class matches:

```
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

In the example above, the `matches()` *"study"* method attempts to match the entire region against the given pattern. Which method you use is generally indicative of what/how you want to match.

***matches()***

> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.

***find()***

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence
>   that matches the pattern.

<sub>*Study methods review the input string and return a Boolean indicating whether or not the pattern is found*</sub>

↳ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html